# Can we make the Open Source (etc.) contributions on Careers draggable for easier ordering?

Tags: feature-request, status-deferred, stack-overflow-jobs

Unlike the image suggests, pressing the up-and-down arrows to re-order the contributions isn't very much fun at all.

[image: Not really fun]

Could they be draggable (maybe by an handle like in [this lazy fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/thhn4h4o/)) for easier ordering?

Edit: It took me like 50-60 clicks to order 10 or so items to somewhat correct position. I added a new item from my Github page that I wanted to showcase first, it appeared on the bottom. I clicked the "up arrow" 10 times to get it first. I added another new repo that I also wanted to showcase. It was also on the bottom. And so on and so on.

Comment: Not sure I see how this is lacking... Clicking a lot of arrows is more cumbersome than free-style ordering would be. There isn't really a lot that can be said beyond that.

Comment: @Andy fun might not have been the right choice of words, but I was in an awfully cheerful mood this morning. Pekka웃 pretty much nailed it: it took me around 50-60 clicks (or more!) to get the order of 10-or-so items to the order I wanted. By drag sorting I could have nailed it with maybe 40 less clicks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is something we may look into in the future. Agree this isn't something that's very pleasant to use, so will look into enhancing this when we revisit the profile design 6 to 8 weeks from now.

Comment: That's awesome! Thanks @jonchan♦